# .zip file created on Mac giving error in Windows 7 upon extracting

Tags: windows-7, mac, zip, 7-zip, winrar

My friend compressed lots of photos into a zip archive using a MacBook, and uploaded it to Dropbox. I downloaded the zip and when I try to extract **using WinRAR** it gives this error, but extracts most of the files:

[image]

And when I try with 7-Zip, it gets stuck and gives this:

[image]

My OS is Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a .rar file when you use winrar. Perhaps it works better. Otherway make on your Mac OS System a tar.gz file winrar can extract this.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible that the .zip file is corrupt. If your friend double-clicks on it in Mac OS X and Mac OS X's built-in default .zip decompressor seems to decompress it without giving a warning/error, that's no surprise since Mac OS X's default zip decompressor doesn't actually check the checksums.

Your friend should use the command-line `zip` utility in Mac OS X to check the zip file for correctness.